# In VSCode , I cant input utf-8 String in java(with Scanner!)

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

in java, i cant input String(with utf-8)

example

```
String str1 = "안녕하세요";
System.out.println("str1");
```

is print

```
안녕하세요
```

but

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
//Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8");
String str1 = "";
str1 = s.nextline();
//str = s.next();
System.out.println(str1);
```

is print

```
안녕하세요 << is typed by me
           << and it's print nothing(in fact " ")
```

how can i config my vscode terminal??

ps.when i typed eng, it worked well.

ps. i use this code

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        String num;

        Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in,"UTF-8");
        System.out.print("입력 : ");
        num = sc1.next();
        System.out.println(num);

        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));
        System.out.print("입력 : ");
        num = sc2.next();
        System.out.println(num);



        sc1.close();
        sc2.close();
    }
```

but its not work also

this is result

```
입력 : 안녕
��     
입력 : 안녕
��
```

Comment: This worked for me. What IDE are you using? Did you save the source (.java) file as UTF-8?

Comment: I've tried: 1. change the encoding to korean; 2.compile and run the code by the command, which specify the encoding style as korean: `javac -encoding EUC-KR Test.java`. still not work. You may put it in github for more help: [vscode-java in github](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues).

Answer (score 1):

you can use utf-8 in scanner like

```
Scanner console = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"));
```